# How to fix Nested query HIVE SQL - syntax error

Tags: sql, hive

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*),
  AVG(result) * 100
FROM
  (
    SELECT CASE WHEN (
      (m1.flag = 1)
      and (m1.Reason = 'reason_1')
    ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS result
    FROM
      db1 m0
      INNER JOIN db2 m1 ON m0.id = m1.id
    WHERE
      col1 <= 3
      AND col2 = 0
  );
```

I'm getting an error on the WHEN CASE clause line, but I don't know what it is (https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/). I can create a table with the nested SELECT clause, but I don't need it and since this is TB worth of data I though of combining both queries. Can I combine the two and would this save me time/space?

Comment: Sql seems to be wrong. Is it something working on some db or its hypothetical? Now you can create slq like this all you need is aliasing. Like this sql works `select c from (select d as c from ( select d from tab) innersql1) innersql2`

Comment: You are missing the select from your derived table. You are also missing the alias for that derived table.

Comment: Thank you, I just didn't know how to even search for this. Alias and derived table were the key terms I needed to know. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments on your post, the sub query needs to be "named" with an alias.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*),
  AVG(result) * 100
FROM
  (
    SELECT CASE WHEN (
      (m1.flag = 1)
      and (m1.Reason = 'reason_1')
    ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS result
    FROM
      db1 m0
      INNER JOIN db2 m1 ON m0.id = m1.id
    WHERE
      col1 <= 3
      AND col2 = 0
  )
    AS alias_name_goes_here
```

That said, you don't even need a sub-query...

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*), 
  AVG(CASE WHEN (m1.flag = 1) and (m1.Reason = 'reason_1') THEN 100 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM
  db1 m0
  INNER JOIN db2 m1 ON m0.id = m1.id
WHERE
  col1 <= 3
  AND col2 = 0
```

Comment: The query is simplified, I have quite a few case when cases. Is there any benefit to doing one way or the other? I find it easier to understand with the subquery